# List(s) objects, different member values, but sharing a "static" member within the list in C#

Tags: c#, list

Here it goes my question:

- I intend to create several lists of objects, being each of the objects from the same class.
- However, within each of the lists, I would like the different instances of the objects to share a common member I could change from any of these instances.
- Of course, each of the lists have its own "static" member.

I hope I had explained myself, I am beginner and I am not sure whether my question has an obvious solution.

Edit: 
I am working on an existing code, and I make every step by doing a trial-error approach. I do not know exactly how to explain it better: I have List list1, and List list2. The set of instances within list1 will have members with different values, but I want to have a member in class A which can be modified from any instance within the list1 and to be common to all the instances in list1. Similarly for list2, but with a different "static" member that the one in list1.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: It would be nice if whoever upvoted the post left comment explaining what OP tries to achieve.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Do you have any code of your progress? Also your post doesn't really have a question in it. Are you asking how to do everything in your list or just the static member part?

Comment: I am working on an existing code, and I make every step by doing a trial-error approach.

Comment: It seems you want to associate a value with the collection itself, and not the values in the collection. Can you clarify that this is what you want?

Comment: It sounds like the user wants to add objects to a collection and have those objects inherit some sort of state or behavior from that collections. For example you have collection of 25% discounted items, you add a item to that collection and query its discount value and get 25%.

Comment: _Possibly_ you want a new class which inherits from List<T> and which defines an additional instance (not static) property. Each object in the list would need a reference to the list which contains it too so an additional property would be needed on whatever type T is.

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen. Yes, it can be said I want to associate a value with the collection itself.   Stephen Kennedy, I guess inheritance can be solution, I will try to implement your suggestion. Thank you very much

Comment: @StephenKennedy It's virtually always wrong to inherit from `List`.  you're not creating a new type of list, rather an object that has both a list an another value.  You should compose a list by creating an object with two properties, a list and whatever the other value is.

Comment: @Servy I understand the point but it then begs the question as to why `List<T>` isn't sealed. Is there any further reading on this topic?

Comment: I would say it should have been sealed, but even though the class isn't sealed, basically none of its methods are virtual, preventing you from actually changing much of any of its behavior, and clearly indicating that it's not a type that is designed to be inherited.

Comment: @Servy, ok, I think I understand your solution. Thank you

Comment: @Servy ...but thereby allowing you to add an additional property and not lose all the benefits of having a List ;) Anyway, thanks, will think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will roughly achieve what you are looking to do. There are many ways to change the structure of the code below to achieve different goals but  basically what you will need to do is create some sort of custom list that when items are added to it, it attaches itself to those items, and removes itself from them when they are removed.

```
public class CustomList : IList<IItem>
{
   public Object CommonMember { get; set; }

   private List<IItem> _internalList = new List<IItem>();
   public void Add(IItem item)
   {
      item.OwnedList = this;
      this._internalList.Add(item);
   }

   public void Remove(IItem item)
   {

     if(this._internalList.Remove(item))
     { item.OwnedList = null; }
   }

   ... you will need to implment more members 
}

public abstract class IItem
{
    public Object OwnedListCommonMember 
    {
        get {
            if(this.OwnedList != null)
            { return this.OwnedList.CommonMember; }
            else { return null; }
        }
    }
    public CustomList OwnedList { get; set; }
}
```